# How to play a video without embedded code in html?

Tags: html, database, video-streaming, windows-media-player

I've got a webpage which works with a MySQLi DB (this is a private website just for our company and it is not something global). Now, I want to upload some videos on server (and not on the DB) and put their links on the website. Now, here is my question: How can I make browser to open Windows Media Player (after clicking on each link by a user) and play the video on the computer, and not on the browser??
As a matter of fact, I do not want the browser to show my videos to users, I want each user to watch videos by Windows Media Player on their computers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Windows Media Player via html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849039/open-windows-media-player-via-html)

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple  should work in your html

```
<a href="/videos/your-video.mp4">video link</a>
```

I video should download, depending on your users prefrences the video may open after its finished downloading... you can't force this

If you want stream then this embed should work:

```
<object id='mediaPlayer' width="320" height="285" 
  classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95' 
  codebase='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701'
  standby='Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...' type='application/x-oleobject'>
  <param name='fileName' value="http://www.yoursite.com/your-video.wmv">
  <param name='animationatStart' value='true'>
  <param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
  <param name='autoStart' value="false">
  <param name='showControls' value="true">
  <param name='loop' value="true">
  <embed type='application/x-mplayer2'
    pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
    id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1' 
    bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1' 
    showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="320" height="285"
    src="http://www.yoursite.com/your-video.wmv" autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="true">
  </embed>
  </object>
```

Note:
You would be better off using html5  tags and converting to mp4 - not that many people use windows media player these days

Comment: As a matter of fact I want the videos to be streamed by Windows Media Player and NOT be downloaded! (although it is possible for users to download them)